# Macbook Pro (Mid 2009) will not turn on without power cord [new battery installed]

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, macos

I have recently purchased and installed a new battery for my Mid 2009 13 inch Macbook Pro but have not been able to turn on the laptop without the power supply since the new battery has been installed. The system report shows that the battery is installed but that it is not charging even though the battery is not at full capacity (83%).

Has anyone experienced a similar issue before? Does anyone know any fixes?

I cannot locate the disks that came with my MBP at the moment so I was also wondering if there was another way to access Apple Hardware Test (AHT)?

Comment: Where did you get this battery? That is, was is purchased from Apple or is it made by another 3rd party manufacturer? Clearly it's a faulty battery (or perhaps was installed incorrectly, though that's not as likely).

Comment: I've been pretty convinced that the battery was faulty the entire time, I was just hoping to try any diagnostics before going through the return process. I'm going to replace with the old and see if the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

There could be a couple of things going on.

The first, and easiest, solution is to reset the SMC. Apple has a KB article on that:

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US

Failing that I would then look at the battery as the cause. Remove it and replace the old one. If it then boots (assuming the old one has ANY charge on it) call the seller and get another battery.

Am I missing anything here?